element's style doesn't apply when passed through components - next.js
i have a component for hero part of every page but its content is different and so its height.
export default function Hero({
  height,
  children,
}: {
  height: string;
  children: ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <div
      className={`flex flex-col h-[${height}] py-1 bg-red-400 text-white items-center justify-center`}
    >
      {children}
    </div>
  );
}

but when im using it the height doesnt apply in page but it does in the developer tool
export default function Page() {
  return (
    <Hero height="500px">
      <Search />
    </Hero>
  );
}


i tried to make the height static to see if something wrong with the hero component itself but it worked fine:
export default function Hero({
  height,
  children,
}: {
  height: string;
  children: ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <div
      className={`flex flex-col h-[80px] py-1 bg-red-400 text-white items-center justify-center`}
    >
      {children}
    </div>
  );
}

but once it's dynamic nothing happens

"the height doesnt apply in page but it does in the developer tool" - all we see there, is that the class h-500px is set on the element. But that doesn't necessarily mean, that there is actual styling associated with that class. Tailwind of course doesn't come with a pre-made height class for every single pixel value you could imagine - it needs to create/apply the styling dynamically. And it looks like that doesn't work as "retroactively", as you would need it here.

@CBroe so what should i do??

@CBroe forget it i figured it out finally thanks!

i should have replaced the whole class name not part of it like this: height="h-[500px]"
